# What will the electric field of a moving charge inside a wire looks like?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

How does an electric field of a moving charge (i.e. electron) inside a wire looks like? Does it looks like this with distorted circular radial lines?

[image]

Comment: This diagram shows the field of a charge which rapidly accelerated to 80% the speed of light. Electrons in a wire do not move nearly that fast.

Comment: @Ghoster is this a correct representation of what electric fields of a moving charge inside a wire look like? https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Electric-field-around-a-current-carrying-conductor-a-Schematic-of-the-application-of-a_fig10_326328996

Comment: No, that’s not the field of a single moving charge. The electrons in a wire have fields which are barely indistinguishable from when they are at rest, because they aren’t moving at relativistic speeds.

Comment: @Ghoster so what does an electric field of a single moving charge in a wire looks like? Any pictures?

Comment: @Ghoster so the electric field still looks like this even when the single charge is moving inside a wire https://study.com/cimages/multimages/16/point_charge.png?

Comment: Yes, but I don’t see why it is useful to think about the field of one electron in a wire. There are trillions of trillions of them and a similar number of nuclei. To high accuracy, their electric fields basically cancel. You should think about the magnetic field caused by the drift current, and, if that is changing with time, the induced electric field. Think about it *macroscopically* rather than *microscopically*.

Comment: @Ghoster I'm curious about what do the electric fields of those trillions of moving electrons inside a wire look like in 3d. Magnetic fields are electric fields and vice versa because the source of both of them is the moving electric current.

Comment: Electric and magnetic fields are related but distinguishable in any given reference frame. One is not the other. Let’s not have a long discussion in comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146096/discussion-between-snoopykid-and-ghoster).

Comment: @Ghoster is this how the electric fields of a moving charge inside a wire look like? https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBW5E.png I don't think the electric field lines are straight when the charge is moving in the wire

Comment: Or do they look like this? https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Electric-Field-of-a-Charged-Particle_fig2_2177605 the one at the far right